# How to write unit test case for angular 8 forms i.e ElementRef.nativeelement.submit()

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular8

I am trying to write unit test case for angular 8 in jasmine. I have a form as below:

```
<form ngNoForm method="post" [action]="url" name="redirect" #redirectForm>
    <input  type= "hidden" name="mesgFromBank" value="{{message}}">
  </form>
```

and my ts file lookes like this:

```
@ViewChild('redirectForm', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) redirectForm: ElementRef;

 this.redirectForm.nativeElement.action = this.url;
 this.redirectForm.nativeElement.firstChild.value = this.message;
 this.redirectForm.nativeElement.submit();
```

However I try to write test case, it will be redirecting to the `this.url` and ultimately it is breaking and I am seeing `"NOT FOUND"` in my Karma runner in browser.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks.